# How to create indicator based on complex combinations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this with many thousands clm_ids: Two clm_ids are given here. clm-ids and tmstp are in any order. Here I have shown tmstp in ascending order for explaining. I have to create an indicator 1 if cd1 is 50/600 and cd2 !=0 otherwise 0 for each clm_id. But for the same clm_id if multiple occurrence of cd1 occurs then I have to see on tmstp which one is the latest and what are their combination. Like for clm_id=1 cd1=50 & cd2=10 sets indicator =1. Down in second row cd1=600 & cd2=10 also sets indicator=1 but in third row cd1=600 & cd2=0 sets that indicator = 0. But still first condition cd1=50 & cd2=10 has indicator = 1 so for this clm_id indicator=1 remains valid. But for clm_id=2, the indicator = 0 since earlier cd1=50 & cd2=10 sets indicator 1 but later cd2=0 so indicator turns to 0. It is complex and hence need your help.

```
clm_id  cd1  cd2  tmstp
1       50 . 10   2019-01-01
1 .     600 .10 . 2010-01-01
1 .     600 .0    2010-01-02
2 .     50   10   2010-01-01
2 .     50 . 0 .  2010-01-02
2 .     42 . 40 . 2010-01-02
```

In the final result the indicator should appear for each clm_id like this:

```
clm_id indicator
1 .     1
2 .     0
```

Initially I was not aware of that for same clm_id cd1 & cd2 combination can change with time(tmstp), therefore I had tried this to set indicator:

```
def add_inj_id(x):
    if (x['cd1'] == 50 or x['cd1'] == 600) and x['cd2'] != '0':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

inj_df['inj_id'] = inj_df.apply(add_inj_id, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can the final result be *sorted* by `clm_id` like you have shown in your example?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even something that you have *discarded* because it was deficient?

Comment: @wwii: yes, I clm_id can be sorted. I tried initially like this:def add_inj_id(x):
    if (x['cd1'] == 50 or x['cd1'] == 600) and x['cd2'] != '-0':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

Comment: inj_df['inj_id'] = inj_df.apply(add_inj_id, axis=1): But this will not work in new scenario. Where cd1 and cd2 combinations are changing with time

Comment: You should include your attempts in your question. When we can see what you have tried (even if it did not work) it helps explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should also show your desired result - For your example DataFrame would your result be `df['indicator'] = [1,1,0,1,0,0]`? It isn't clear  (to me) how the `tmstp` affects the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If needed *convert* `'tmstp'` to DateTime so comparisons can be made:

```
df['tmstp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tmstp'])
```

Group the DataFrame by `'clm_id'`:

```
gb = df.groupby('clm_id')
```

Keep a list of namedtuple's for the results

```
import collections
results = []
Result = collections.namedtuple('Result',['clm_id','indicator'])
```

Iterate over the `'clm_id'` groups; for each `clm_id` split by `'cd1'`; find the most recent `cd1` and determine if its `cd2` is not zero; Check if either the `50` or `600` subgroup is True; store the result.

```
for clm_id,group in gb:
    cd1_grp = group.groupby('cd1')
    # Start with the indicators set to False
    ind = {50:False,600:False}
    for cd1,subgroup in cd1_grp:
        if cd1 not in (50,600):
            continue
        most_recent = subgroup.loc[subgroup['tmstp'].idxmax()]
        ind[cd1] = most_recent.cd2 != 0
    indicator = (ind[50] or ind[600]) * 1
    results.append(Result(clm_id,indicator))

>>> results
[Result(clm_id=1, indicator=1), Result(clm_id=2, indicator=0)]

>>> pd.DataFrame(results)
   clm_id  indicator
0       1          1
1       2          0
>>>
```

---

I used nested for loops (double groupby) to work out the logic. Here is a better version - grouping with two columns.

```
gb1 = df.groupby(['clm_id','cd1'])
d = {}
for (clm_id,cd1),group in gb1:
    if clm_id not in d:
        d[clm_id]=0
    if cd1 not in (50,600):
        continue
    most_recent = group.loc[group['tmstp'].idxmax()]
    d[clm_id] = d[clm_id] or int(most_recent.cd2 != 0)

>>> d
{1: 1, 2: 0}
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()),columns=['clm_id','indicator'])
   clm_id  indicator
0       1          1
1       2          0
>>>
```

The dictionary could be made with `d = dict.fromkeys(df['clm_id'].unique(),0)`. That would make the `if clm_id not in d:...` conditional statement unnecessary. Not clear how that would affect performance.

---

Test DataFrame

```
import io
s = '''clm_id  cd1  cd2  tmstp
1       50  10   2019-01-01
1      600 10  2010-01-01
1      600 0    2010-01-02
2      50   10   2010-01-01
2      50  0   2010-01-02
2      42  40  2010-01-02'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), delimiter='\s+')
```